# Swift3 CoreData with Extension

Tags: core-data, swift3, xcode8, ios10, ios-app-extension

I'm working on core data with extensions, and having errors below.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error:  is not a valid NSFetchRequest.'

It's working well on host app still, however crashing on extensions with the same codes.

Debugger stopped when executed managedObjectContext.fetch(request)

```
func getDataString() -> String {

    var result = ""

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "DataString", in: managedObjectContext)!
    let request : NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = DataString.fetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    do {
        let results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
        printDebug(message: "\tDataString Count : \(results.count)")

        if results.count > 0 {
            let row = results[0] as! NSManagedObject

            result = row.value(forKey: "data") as! String
        }
    } catch let error {
        printDebug(message: "ERROR : getDataString fetch")
        setErrorLog(errorText: "\(error)")
    }

    return result
}
```

This crashes even though written with try-catch.
Please help.

Comment: first check entity name and request.entity is getting or not.

Comment: @ChandanJee Checked it. No problem on entity name, and this works well on host app. This error only occurs on extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer myself.

```
func getDataString() -> String {

var result = ""

let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DataString")

do {
    let results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
    printDebug(message: "\tDataString Count : \(results.count)")

    if results.count > 0 {
        let row = results[0] as! NSManagedObject

        result = row.value(forKey: "data") as! String
    }
} catch let error {
    printDebug(message: "ERROR : getDataString fetch")
    setErrorLog(errorText: "\(error)")
}

return result }
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

The generic type of your `NSFetchRequest` has to be `DataString`:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<DataString> = DataString.fetchRequest()

managedObjectContext.perform {
    do {
        let results = request.execute()
    } catch let error {
        ...
    }
}
```